# Populating user image and text posts, compiles and runs but cells are empty. Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to populate my feed of images and text users post. The code compiles and runs but I get empty cells.

```
var titles = [String]()
var locations = [String]()
var dates = [String]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var privacySettingQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    privacySettingQuery.whereKey("privacy", equalTo: true)
    privacySettingQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

               self.titles.append(object["name"] as! String)
               self.dates.append(object["dateTime"] as! String)
               self.locations.append(object["location"] as! String)
               self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
            }
        }
    }
}    
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return titles.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostsCell

    postsCell.postImage.image = UIImage(named: "Post-Image-   Placeholder-1.png")
    postsCell.postTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    postsCell.postLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]
    postsCell.postDate.text = dates[indexPath.row]

    return postsCell
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also is there a better way to do this other than using arrays?

Comment: Can you post your numberOfRowsInSection method? And it's better to make a model class instead of 4 arrays to manage your data.

Comment: I am new to iOS development. Could you explain what a model class is? Also, I fixed the fatal error but now get empty cells

Comment: I post the answer, hope that can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the empty issue.You need call tableView.reloadData() after you got the objects. 
Model class like

```
class Post: NSObject {
    var title: String
    var location: String
    var date: NSDate
    var imageFile: PFFile
}
```

And in viewController use

```
var posts: [Post]?
```

instead of the 4 arrays

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what a model class is? Ive never heard of using one

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Answer (score 0):

When this code is being called

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
return titles.count
}
```

The value for `titles.count` is still 0. After you finish fetching the info from parse and you have values for the arrays you must reload the UITableView. To do this make an outlet for the UITableView and call it tableView. Then call this code `tableView.reloadData()`

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put tableView.reloadData() in view did load?